# Symfony: Form Builder doesn't get OneToMany inputs

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, one-to-many, formbuilder

So I have `OneToMany` relation between two entities and I have created the related form to it, but it seems that the `FormBuilder`, after sending data, doesn't see the children of the entity.
**Parent class:**

```
class Parent{
   /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

   private $id;

   /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
   private $name;

   /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Child",mappedBy="parent",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
   private $children;
}
```

**Child class:**

```
class Child{
    /**
      * @var int
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      */
    private $id;
     /**
      * @var string
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
      */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Parent", inversedBy="children")
     */
    private $parent;
}
```

**This is FormTypes:**

```
class ParentType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')
            ->add('children', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => ChildType::class,
            'allow_add' => true

        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Bundle\Entity\Parent'
        ));
    }

}
```

**Child FormType:**

```
class ChildType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Bundle\Entity\Child'
        ));
    }
}
```

After that I have created my form inside the controller like this:

```
function saveAction(Request $request){
    $parent = new Parent();
    $form = $this->createForm('Bundle\Form\ParentType', $parent);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            //--after submitted the form I just want to display the children
            die(var_dump($parent->getChildren()));


        }
}
```

Of course I'm creating the children using jquery from data-prototype provided by symfony's `FormBuilder`, but the form doesn't see them !!
What am I missing here ?

Comment: You can use `query_builder` property like shown here: [Full webform style CRUD example with an embedded associated entity in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/djrc/full-webform-style-crud-example-with-an-embedded-associated-entity-in-symfony)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because your 'setters' are not being called.

Try adding `by_reference` and setting it to `false` like this:

```
class ParentType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')
            ->add('children', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => ChildType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false

        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Bundle\Entity\Parent'
        ));
    }

}
```

I don't have time to actually test your code. However, you shouldn't have to put `parent` in your `child` form. So your child formType should look like this:

```
class ChildType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')      ;

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Bundle\Entity\Child'
        ));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes you're right about putting the parent in the child formtype but setting "by_reference" to false still not working.